# Laravel using variable from database in custom blade directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

#### Summary

A custom blade directive does not use the current value in the database without clearing the view cache first. Since that value can be changed by the user and affects the view I need the directive to always pull the current value from the DB, not use the cached one (this works for directives like @auth, so why not my custom one?).

#### Background

I have written a custom directive using [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-writing-custom-blade-directives), it does basically the same thing shows different content depending on a value stored in the database. The problem I'm running into is if the variable changes from false to true for example, the directive is stuck with the old value, it doesn't update it when it is changed in the DB. It does work when I clear the view cache, but I want it to always use the current value stored in the database.

#### Code

```
\Blade::directive('signup_done', function () {
    $condition = false;

    if (\Auth::check()) {
        if (\Auth::user()->signup_done) $condition = true;
    }

    return "<?php if ($condition) { ?>";
});
```

#### Expected vs actual results

`signup_done` is `false` by default for each user, if it changes to `true` I want the directive to output true, but it's stuck in false until I clear the view cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade is caching the return string of your custom directive, but if that string is a PHP code, it will be evaluated when the cached view is accessed. What you can do is to include the entire conditional logic in the return string, as in:

```
\Blade::directive('signup_done', function () {
    return "<?php if (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->signup_done) { ?>";
});
```

It may not be the best solution, but is the one that should work.

Comment: The simplest solutions are sometimes right in front of us. Thanks! I agree that this feels like a dirty way of doing things now, is there a better way of handling this scenario that you can think of?

Comment: Not really. You can see that the framework code itself does a similar thing: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesConditionals.php

There is a way to inject the dynamic value to the return string of the directive (as closure arguments), but you'd have to pass it from the view, as in `@signup_done(true)`. In this particular case I think this would defeat the purpose of your directive though.

Comment: Right you are they do do it similarly, well it works great now so thanks for your help once again :)

Comment: @Brainmaniac It encapsulates the block of code to be rendered when the directive is true in the blade template. I use it together with a closing `@end` which returns the closing brace. Could also be a colon and an endif which I think is more prevalent in Laravel but I prefer curly braces.

Comment: aa ok tnx gottcha